# CSS ul li with display:inline-block but position is wrong

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-position

I have an ul. and li s with display inline-block.
In each li, i have an image, and a div in bottom the image.
The position of lis are not same if the divs have different row 
Heres the image.
[image: a]

Note: I dont use that images. its just for test :)

Heres the CSS code:

```
.uldaftarartikel ul{<br/>
    list-style-type: none;margin: 0 auto;padding: 0;text-align:center;<br/>
}<br/>
.uldaftarartikel ul li{<br/>
    display: inline-block; margin:7px;width: 170px;height: 272px;<br/>
}<br/>
@media (min-width: 700px) and (max-width: 1299px){<br/>
    .uldaftarartikel ul li{width: 200px;}<br/>
}<br/>
@media (min-width: 1300px){<br/>
    .uldaftarartikel ul li{width: 227px;}<br/>
}<br/>
.uldaftarartikel ul li a{<br/>
    display: block;text-decoration: none;height: 272px;<br/>
}<br/>
.uldaftarartikel ul li a:hover{<br/>
    text-decoration: none;<br/>
}<br/>

.uldaftarartikel ul li a .gambarartikelchange{<br/>
    background-color: transparent;<br/>
}<br/>
.uldaftarartikel ul li a .gambarartikelchange:hover{<br/>
    background: rgb(255,241,103);<br/>
}<br/>
.uldaftarartikel ul li a .gambarartikelchange img{<br/>
    width: 100%;height: auto;opacity:1;transition:opacity 1.5s;height: 112px;<br/>-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;-ms-transform: translateZ(0); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */transform: translateZ(0);<br/>
}<br/>
.uldaftarartikel ul li a .gambarartikelchange img:hover{<br/>
    opacity: 0.4;<br/>
}<br/>
.uldaftarartikel ul li a .keterangandaftarartikel{<br/>
    color: rgb(127,71,51);transition:color 1.5s;height: 150px;padding:5px;<br/>
}<br/>
.uldaftarartikel ul li a .keterangandaftarartikel:hover{<br/>
    color:rgb(204,88,47);<br/>
}<br/>
```

Heres the HTML code:

```
<div class="uldaftarartikel"><br/>
<ul><br/>
  <li><a href="#"><div class="gambarartikelchange"><img src="gambarartikel/1.jpg" ></div><div class="keterangandaftarartikel">fqwgegg<br/>asfagdg</div></a></li><br/>
  <li><a href="#"><div class="gambarartikelchange"><img src="gambarartikel/2.jpg" ></div><div class="keterangandaftarartikel">3yrehdfh</div></a></li><br/>
  <li><a href="#"><div class="gambarartikelchange"><img src="gambarartikel/3.jpg" ></div><div class="keterangandaftarartikel">hshfdh5fdhj</div></a></li><br/>
  <li><a href="#"><div class="gambarartikelchange"><img src="gambarartikel/4.jpg" ></div><div class="keterangandaftarartikel">4yhuredhdt</div></a></li><br/>
  <li><a href="#"><div class="gambarartikelchange"><img src="gambarartikel/1.jpg" ></div><div class="keterangandaftarartikel">fqwgegg</div></a></li><br/>
  <li><a href="#"><div class="gambarartikelchange"><img src="gambarartikel/2.jpg" ></div><div class="keterangandaftarartikel">3yrehdfh</div></a></li><br/>
  <li><a href="#"><div class="gambarartikelchange"><img src="gambarartikel/3.jpg" ></div><div class="keterangandaftarartikel">hshfdh5fdhj</div></a></li><br/>
  <li><a href="#"><div class="gambarartikelchange"><img src="gambarartikel/4.jpg" ></div><div class="keterangandaftarartikel">4yhuredhdt</div></a></li><br/>
</ul><br/>
</div><br/>
```

Maybe its simple, but i feel badman :), so i got headache lol. Ty man!

Comment: Add the actual code instead of images.

Comment: use ul li{float:left;}

Comment: Ty man.. the answer is ul li{float:left} @HirenPatel. Ty man..

Comment: @cheyong most welcome man.

Comment: The cause of the problem is the vertical alignment, which is set to `baseline` de default. Using `vertical-align:top` instead of floating would also solve the issue.

Comment: @MrLister Yea it also solves the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this .uldaftarartikel ul li{float:left}

Answer (score 0):

The correct answers are :
1. .uldaftarartikel ul li{float:left} Ty @HirenPatel.
2. .uldaftarartikel ul li{vertical-align:top} Ty @MrLister.

Why cant i check their comment as answer? Im sorry im new in the forum :)
And noob in css hahahaha

Comment: Added comment as answer so you can check as answer,i added answer as comment beacause you have not added actual html and css code when i added comment